# Include parameters inside ASP.NET Core REST URLs

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have a project that contains reports. Reading up on Rest best practices it looks like I should have a URL like the following to a page that lists all of the reports:

```
http://../Projects/23/Reports
```

To view a specific report I would use a link like the following:

```
http://../Projects/23/Reports/2
```

I've tried a number of ways to build these links with asp tag helpers without luck. For example:

```
<a asp-page="/Projects/{pid}/Reports/{rid}" asp-route-pid="@item.ID" asp-route-rid="@report.ID" >View Report</a>
```

By default it looks like asp-route-* will tack those items on as parameters (ie ?pid=23&rid=2) and that might work but that doesn't seem like the recommended URLs.

Comment: The problem is that you're using Razor Pages. Among other things, you can't really achieve this style of routing, because routes are based on the file system. It's just one of the many, many, many reasons Razor Pages sucks. Go Core MVC and don't look back.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your custom razor page routing next to the @page directive in your *.cshtml file.

```
@page "{pid}/{rid}"
```

This will have as a result you will have the following URL when your razor page is Projects.cshtml.

```
/Projects/23/2
```

You can also add static information in your URL.

```
@page "{pid}/Reports/{rid}"
```

Now your URL will be

```
/Projects/23/Reports/2
```

If you want to define the routing for all the razor pages you can see how I did it in order to define the current language in this post.

[Asp.net core Localization always returns english clulture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398474/asp-net-core-localization-always-returns-english-clulture/47413617#47413617)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is the right direction and would probably work if the files are in the same directory. I have the Reports/Index in subfolder and razor-page folder routing seems to take precedence. For example this tag helper asp-page="./Reports/Index" asp-route-pid="@item.ID"  and this page directive @page "{pid}/Reports" generates this URL:  .../Projects/Reports/130/Reports

Comment: Try to remove the dot. Use "/Reports/Index" instead of "./Reports/Index"