# Asp.net core Localization always returns english clulture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, localization

I am trying to develop a multilanguage project.For static value I used resource(.resx file )

I create two resources file
Home.resx(default or English) and home.resx(for the Arabic language)
it works for default or English

Then I try to change language

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
 var home = Resources.Home.Home1;
```

But it still return English value instead of Arabic value

here is my startup.cs Configure function

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

   var supportedCultures = new List<System.Globalization.CultureInfo>
            {
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"),

                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AR"),

            };
            var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
......
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you need to follow the [naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#resource-file-naming) more closely. So your file should probably be named `Home.ar.resx`.

Comment: @poke I change it Home.ar.resx but it still get default(english) value.How can I set arabic cultur?is this wrong? is this line enough? System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AR");// or ("ar")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I will tell you what I do in my projects. Type the following code after services.AddMvc() in your ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs.

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
    new CultureInfo("el-GR"),
};

var MyOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
MyOptions.RequestCultureProviders = new[]
{
     new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { RouteDataStringKey = "lang", Options = MyOptions }
};

services.AddSingleton(MyOptions);
```

Now define the following class in your project

```
public class LocalizationPipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
}
```

Change your default routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{lang=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In use the MiddlewareFilter for each of your controllers.

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string GetCulture()
    {
        return $"CurrentCulture:{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}, CurrentUICulture:{CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}";
    }
}
```

You can change the current language like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("EN", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string, new { lang = "en-US" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("FR", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string, new { lang = "fr-FR" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("GR", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string, new { lang = "el-GR" })</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to support Razor Pages as well, make the following changes. Add the following change the servcies.AddMvc().

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
        {
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
            {
                var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
                attributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{lang=el-GR}", attributeRouteModel.Template);
            }
        });
    });
```

Use the following MiddlewareFilter attribute over your PageModels

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))]
public class ContactModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = "Your contact page.";
    }
}
```

The only thing that I have not managed to do is to automatically define the LocalizationPipeline for all the controllers and PageModels by adding the MiddlewareFilter programmatically inside the Startup.cs.

Comment: is this so hard:) I just want to set current cultur if user click change language to arabic or other language

Comment: This is the only way that I managed to implement it but if you set it up properly, it works.

Comment: Yes it works and there is no performance issues..Thank you very much...I want to change route.With your code it generate that url: http://localhost:49531/ar/Flight/List?currencyCode=KWD  how can I change to  http://localhost:49531/ar/kwd/MyFlights

Comment: In order to include your currencyCode you have to use the following route

`{lang=en-US}/{currencycode}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`